# How to plot planar graphs as such?

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

A planar graph is a graph that can be drawn in the plane such that no two edges cross.

For example, the graph `Graph[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {1, 4}, {3, 4}, {2, 4}}]` is planar, and can be shown in both of these ways:

[image]

The layout in the left doesn't have crossing edges and it's immediately obvious that the graph is planar.  The layout on the right is what Mathematica gives me by default.

**Question:** How can a planar graph be shown without any crossing edges in Mathematica?

---

I expect `` Combinatorica` `` might have this feature as it has a `PlanarQ` function, but unfortunately the documentation is not included with Mathematica and I have not been able to find out how to do this.

Testing whether a `Graph` is planar is possible like this:

```
<< GraphUtilities`
PlanarQ@ToCombinatoricaGraph[someGraph]
```

Note: The above way of testing planarity is for version 8 or earlier. The `PlanarGraphQ` built-in function was introduced in version 9.

---

Here's a random set of planar graph of different sizes to test on:

```
<< ComputationalGeometry`
graphs = DeleteDuplicates[
   Flatten@Table[
     Graph@
      Union[Sort /@ 
        Join @@ (Thread /@ 
           DelaunayTriangulation@RandomReal[1, {j, 2}])],
     {10}, {j, 4, 10}
     ], IsomorphicGraphQ];
```

---

To avoid confusion, I'd like to note that the `` ComputationalGeometry`PlanarGraphPlot[] `` function does not do what I need.  It does not lay out a graph.  One needs to provide an explicit list of vertex coordinates to it.  I have a graph as the input, I know that it's planar, and need a layout algorithm that will draw the graph without intersecting edges.

Comment: What do you mean: *the documentation is not included with Mathematica*?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The full documentation of ``Combinatorica` `` is not included.  It has to be [bought separately](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0521806860).

Comment: Did you try selecting `RadialDrawing` in the right-click context menu under `Graph Layout`. For this example it gives the graph on the left.

Comment: On the other hand, `GraphData["TetrahedralGraph"]` is drawn such that it is obviously planar...

Comment: @kguler I tried that and other options... it gives the correct plot for the first example and for a few in the second bigger list of graphs, but not all...

Comment: `GraphData["Classes"]` returns 163 classes of which oneis `"Planar"` and `GraphData["Planar"]` returns 2923 graphs. Perhaps, this list could serve as some sort of look-up table?

Comment: This paper, posted by @halirutan in chat, seems to suggest this is not a trivial thing to do: http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/schacht/2011/untangle.pdf

Comment: @kguler Even the graphs returned by `GraphData` don't contain vertex position information, so it doesn't solve the visualization problem.  *Testing* planarity is not a problem, `PlanarQ` does that. Also, lookup tables with graphs are really problematic because they require a lot of isomorphism testing (which can be slow---and version 8.0.4 `IsomorphicGraphQ` is still buggy unfortunately)

Comment: Have a look at Help > Documentation Center > ComputationalGeometry/ref/PlanarGraphPlot

Comment: @Daniel I found that function, but it requires a set of points (coordinate pairs) as input and it simply shows a Delaunay triangulation of these points.  It does not seem to take a graph as input without explicit point coordinates.  I only have the graph (e.g. as an adjacency list), I can test using `PlanarQ` that it is indeed a planar graph, and now I would like to show it as a planar graph (i.e. without intersecting edges)

Comment: MathGroup version here: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/_lxnrJ0fufc/discussion

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can plot it using the `GraphLayout` option, which has, since v9, "PlanarEmbedding" as a possible value:

```
Graph[Rule @@@ {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {1, 4}, {3, 4}, {2, 4}}, GraphLayout -> "PlanarEmbedding"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics].

(BTW: This is the standard Mathematica `Graph`, not the Combinatorica `Graph` function)

Another one:

```
truncatedCube =
  {{0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
   {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, 
   {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

AdjacencyGraph[truncatedCube, 
  GraphLayout -> "PlanarEmbedding", 
  VertexLabels -> Array[# -> # &, Length @ truncatedCube], 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0.5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Without `GraphLayout -> "PlanarEmbedding"`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Excellent!  I do wonder if this (new in version 9) method is *guaranteed* to find a planar embedding if one exists.

Comment: @Szabolcs since v9 there's also `PlanarGraphQ`. I suppose that mma will try to find the solution if it knows it exists. Anyway, the documentation says nothing about this but I tried quite a few cases.

Comment: I wrote support and they confirmed (in less than 24 hrs!!) that if the graph is planar, this method should *always* find a planar embedding (i.e. it's not a heuristic method).  I'll mention `PlanarGraphQ` in the question in case people read it.

Comment: @Szabolcs Great!

Comment: Is it possible to do this given a graph taken from `GraphData`?

Comment: @Juan Why wouldn't that be the case? `GraphData` graphs are just graphs. Try for instance `Graph[GraphData[{"TriangularHoneycombObtuseKnight", 5}] // EdgeList //  Graph, GraphLayout -> "PlanarEmbedding"]`

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I don't know what these `//` mean, but I tried `Graph[EdgeList[GraphData["BislitCube"]], 
 GraphLayout -> "PlanarEmbedding"]` and it worked!. Edit: OK I think they are some way to do function composition. This works too: `Graph[GraphData["BislitCube"] // EdgeList, 
 GraphLayout -> "PlanarEmbedding"]`.

Comment: @juan Functions can be entered in Mathematica in a standard format with fun[arg], prefix form as fun@arg, infix as arg1~fun~arg2, and postfix form as arg//fun. Sometimes, one of the forms is more convenient or fits more with your mental image of the program flow. Note that precedence of the various forms differs.

Answer (score 17):

I wouldn't know how to do this automatically but you could untangle the graphs manually using `Manipulate`:

```
untangle[gr_] :=
 DynamicModule[{edges, vv, plrnge, gap},
  gap = .15;
  edges = EdgeList[gr];
  vv = VertexList[gr];
  plrnge = 
   Through[{Min, Max}[#]] & /@ 
    Transpose[
     OptionValue[AbsoluteOptions[gr, VertexCoordinates], 
      VertexCoordinates]];
  Manipulate[
   pt = Round[pt, .15];
   Graph[vv, edges, VertexCoordinates -> pt,
    EdgeStyle -> {{Darker[Gray], Thickness[Large]}},
    VertexSize -> 0,
    GridLines -> (Range[Floor[#1 - 1, gap], #2 + 1, gap] & @@@ plrnge),
    GridLinesStyle -> Opacity[.3],
    PlotRange -> plrnge + {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
    Epilog -> {EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Red], 
      Disk[#, .03] & /@ pt}],
   {{pt, OptionValue[AbsoluteOptions[gr, VertexCoordinates],
      VertexCoordinates]}, Locator, Appearance -> None},
   Button["Paste graph", Print[Graph[vv, edges, VertexCoordinates -> pt]]]]]
```

**Example**

For some arbitrary test graph this looks like

```
<< ComputationalGeometry`
graph = Graph@
   Union[Sort /@ 
     Join @@ (Thread /@ DelaunayTriangulation@RandomReal[1, {20, 2}])];
untangle[graph]
```

Before:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And after manually untangling the vertices:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The pasted untangled graph looks like:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It's not that easy to do the untangling even manually though.

Comment: No, I know. Maybe you could turn it into a puzzle and let other people do the untangling :-)

Comment: I could make a web based game, and feed all my graphs to the visitors :D

Comment: That's how I am usually suckered into solving other people's problems.

Comment: SE is a big game, isn't it? :D

Comment: @Szabolcs comments above quoted in my profile.

Comment: @Szabolcs There is already a nice web-based planarity game at http://www.planarity.net

Comment: and also an [Entangled](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.rychtar.android.entangledgame) game for android.

Answer (score 4):

There are the built-in `"PlanarEmbedding"` and `"TutteEmbedding"` `GraphLayout`s.

[IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) brings additional planar graph visualization functions, `IGLayoutPlanar` and `IGLayoutTutte`. `IGLayoutPlanar` implements a different algorithm than `"PlanarEmbedding"` and `IGLayoutTutte` allows specifying the outer face, and considers edge weights (the builtin one can do neither). In addition to IGraph/M's documentation, there are some demos [in this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/185478/12).