# Generating graphs interactively (GUI)

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, dynamic, gui-construction

I want to create graphs interactively using a GUI. I thought of using a `ClickPane[]` environment. The code I have (in part borrowed from the Documentation) works perfectly to generate a visual representation of the graph:

```
DynamicModule[{vertex, g},
 vertex = {};
 g = Graph[{}];
 Dynamic@EventHandler[
   Framed@Graphics[{Point[vertex], Line[vertex]}, PlotRange -> 1], 
   "MouseDown" :> 
    AppendTo[vertex, Round[MousePosition["Graphics"], 0.1]], 
   "MouseDown" :> VertexAdd[g, {vertex}]]]
```

The problem I am facing is how to generate a *real* graph, not just an image of it, so I can work on it with *Mathematica*. If I evaluate the code above outside a `DynamicModule[]`, and try to visualise the graph `g`, a blank image is returned.

I would like to use the two cartesian points that define each `Line[]` as vertices, but *Mathematica* does not allow me to do that (from what I have read). `VertexCoordinates` is not really helpful since it's only an option, and not a primitive.

I'm wondering if there's a way to register a `MouseClick` as a number, for example *first, second, third*, etc. and then use that information to add vertices to a blank graph. My attempt at this workaround has failed. I wrote a `For[]` loop that counted how many points there were in `vertex` and assigned a letter to each position. The graph then generated will always be a straight line, unless I define the `VertexCoordinates`, but then I still have to create the edges in an automatic and reliable way, which is beyond me for now.

How should I proceed to generate such graphs?

**EDIT**: Turns out I was wrong. There *is* such functionality available in *Mathematica*. While Heike's answer is great for what I need to do (I can fully customize the graph creation process), the interested should take a look at the following: [GraphEdit](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/GraphUtilities/ref/GraphEdit.html) and [GraphEditor](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/GUIKit/tutorial/GraphEditor.html).

Comment: There are actually two graph editors that come with Mathematica.  One is `GraphEdit` from the ``GraphUtilities` `` package, which you have discovered, and another one is a [GUIKit example, also called `GraphEdit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/GUIKit/tutorial/GraphEditor.html)  I like the latter one a bit better.

Comment: If you use `GraphPlot` to produce the graph and then double-click the output you can edit the vertices and edges of the graph interactively without losing the connections (requires some care with mouse focus)

Comment: [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2531/46) might be of help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could do create a simple graph editing tool to create a graph from scratch by doing something like this. To add edges you just click and drag.

```
DynamicModule[{pt1, pt2, ind1, ind2, pts = {}, edges = {}, cedge = {}},
 Manipulate[
  EventHandler[
   Dynamic@Graphics[
     {Line[pts[[#]] & /@ edges],
      cedge, {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[pts]}}, PlotRange -> 1],
   {"MouseDown" :>
     (pt2 = pt1 = Round[MousePosition["Graphics"], 0.1];
      ind1 = PadRight[Flatten[Position[pts, pt1]], 1, Length[pts] + 1][[1]]),
    "MouseDragged" :>
     (pt2 = Round[MousePosition["Graphics"], 0.1]; 
      cedge = {Gray, Dashed, Line[{pt1, pt2}]}),
    "MouseUp" :>
     (pt2 = Round[MousePosition["Graphics"], 0.1];
      If[ind1 == Length[pts] + 1, AppendTo[pts, pt1]];
      ind2 = PadRight[Flatten[Position[pts, pt2]], 1, Length[pts] + 1][[1]];
      If[ind2 == Length[pts] + 1, AppendTo[pts, pt2]];
      If[ind1 =!= ind2, AppendTo[edges, {ind1, ind2}]];
      cedge = {})}],

  Row[{Button["Paste",
     Print[Graph[Range[Length[pts]], edges, VertexCoordinates -> pts]]],
   Button["Clear", pts = {}; edges = {}]}]]]
```

Screenshot:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Pasted graph:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Heike, this is very close to what I am looking for, except that I want to be able to select and drag the points. - Anyway, I tried this code and when I click the Paste button after I added some vertices and edges I get the following message: " Null is not a Graphics primitive or directive. "

Comment: Worked well for me. Mathematica 10.3.0 / Win 7.

Answer (score 16):

This is a bit more complicated, but I did this for a human experiment previously, so why not share it.

The code keeps track of nodes and edges of a graph that can be manipulated:

- new edges can be drawn by dragging the mouse from one node to the other
- edges can be deleted via right-click menu
- nodes can be moved by dragging while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
- node can be deleted via right-click menu
- new nodes can be added via the button above the graph

Known issues: sometimes the arrow indicating the position of the new edge is not displayed, because the `EventHandler` does not recognize the `"MouseDragged"` event. Still the edge is created correctly.

**Edit**

Added definition for `Pos` as it was a packaged function I forgot to include. Renamed it to `firstPosition`.

```
DynamicModule[{
  $MaxNodes = 10, r = .1, range = {-2, 2}, snap = .4,
  defNodes = 5, nodes, nodeList = None, edgeList, nodeCoord, labels,
  selectedEdge, selectedNode, nodePos, tail, tailCoord, headCoord, 
  arrowUp, edgeMenuUp, nodeMenuUp, nodeMenuPos, edgeMenuPos, key,
  reset, update, closestPoint, circleLayout,
  selectEdge, deselectEdge, moveEdge, snapEdge, deleteEdge, 
  reverseEdge, selectNode, moveNode, deselectNode, addNode, 
  deleteNode, firstPosition},


 (* Initialization code *)
firstPosition[list_, case_] := Position[list, case, 1, 1][[1, 1]];

 arrowUp = 
  edgeMenuUp = 
   nodeMenuUp = 
    False;(* switches to indicate if there is interaction with \
arrow/edge menu/node menu *)
 selectedNode = tail = {};


 (* Output *)
 Deploy@EventHandler[
   Column@{
     Row@{Button["Add node", addNode[], ImageSize -> 100], 
       Button["Reset", reset[], ImageSize -> 100], 
       Button["Rearrange", circleLayout[], ImageSize -> 100]},
     Panel[Graphics[
       {

        Dynamic[{
            AbsoluteThickness@1, Arrowheads@.04,
            EventHandler[
             {If[selectedEdge === #, Darker@Red, Black],

              Dynamic[Arrow[(List @@ #) /. nodeCoord, r], 
               TrackedSymbols :> {nodeCoord}],

              If[edgeMenuUp, 
               Inset[ActionMenu[Dynamic["", (edgeMenuUp = False) &], {
                  "reverse" :> reverseEdge@selectedEdge,

                  "delete" :> (edgeMenuUp = False; 
                    deleteEdge@selectedEdge)
                  }, Appearance -> None, ImageSize -> 20, 
                 AutoAction -> True], edgeMenuPos], {}]},
             {
              {"MouseDown", 2} :> (selectedEdge = #; 
                edgeMenuPos = MousePosition["Graphics", Graphics]; 
                edgeMenuUp = True),
              {"MouseUp", 2} :> (selectedEdge = edgeMenuPos = {}; 
                edgeMenuUp = False)
              }, PassEventsDown -> False, PassEventsUp -> False]
            } & /@ edgeList, 
         TrackedSymbols :> {edgeList, edgeMenuPos, edgeMenuUp, 
           selectedEdge}],


        AbsoluteThickness@1, GrayLevel@.5,
        Dynamic[If[arrowUp, Arrow[{tailCoord, headCoord}], {}], 
         TrackedSymbols :> {arrowUp, headCoord, tailCoord}],

        EdgeForm@{Black, Opacity@.7},
        Dynamic[(
          {EventHandler[{
               Dynamic[{

                 If[selectedNode === #, Hue[1, 1, .7], 
                  Hue[.6, .2, .8]],
                 Disk[# /. nodeCoord, r]}, 
                TrackedSymbols :> {selectedNode, nodeCoord}],

               If[nodeMenuUp, 
                Inset[ActionMenu[
                  Dynamic[
                   "", (nodeMenuUp = 
                    False) &], {"delete" :> (nodeMenuUp = False; 
                    deleteNode@selectedNode)}, Appearance -> None, 
                  ImageSize -> 20, AutoAction -> True], 
                 nodeMenuPos], {}]},
              {

               "MouseDown" :> (If[(key = CurrentValue@"ControlKey"), 
                  selectNode@#, selectEdge@#]),
               "MouseDragged" :> (If[key, moveNode[], moveEdge[]]),

               "MouseUp" :> (If[key, deselectNode[], deselectEdge[]]; 
                 key = False),
               {"MouseDown", 2} :> (selectedNode = #; 
                 nodeMenuPos = MousePosition["Graphics", Graphics]; 
                 nodeMenuUp = True),
               {"MouseUp", 2} :> (selectedNode = nodeMenuPos = {}; 
                 nodeMenuUp = False)
               }, PassEventsDown -> False, PassEventsUp -> False],

             Dynamic[
              Style[Text[# /. labels, # /. nodeCoord, 
                Scaled@{-.6, -.6}], Gray, FontFamily -> "Ariel", 15], 
              TrackedSymbols :> {nodeCoord}]
             } & /@ nodeList
          ), 
         TrackedSymbols :> {nodeList, nodeMenuUp, nodeMenuPos(* 
           do NOT put selectedNode here as it disables node movement! \
*)}]
        }
       , PlotRange -> {range, range}, Background -> White, 
       PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 15, ImageMargins -> 0, 
       AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> False, Frame -> False, 
       FrameTicks -> All]

      , FrameMargins -> 0, ImageMargins -> 0, 
      ImageSize -> {400, Automatic}]}

   , {{"MouseDown", 2} :> {}}, PassEventsDown -> True],


 Initialization :> (

   (* accepts coordinates in the form: {1 -> Subscript[coord, 1], 
   3 -> Subscript[coord, 3], ...} *)
   closestPoint[pt_List, all_List, d_: Infinity] := Module[{dist},
     dist = EuclideanDistance[pt, #] & /@ (Last /@ all);
     If[Min@dist > d, {}, all[[First@Ordering@dist, 1]]]
     ];
   circleLayout[n_Integer] := 
    N@Table[{Cos[2 \[Pi]/n i], Sin[2 \[Pi]/n i]}, {i, n}];

   selectEdge[node_] := (tail = node; 
     tailCoord = headCoord = node /. nodeCoord; arrowUp = True);
   moveEdge[] := 
    If[tail =!= {}, headCoord = MousePosition["Graphics", Graphics]];
   snapEdge[] := Module[{head, new},
     head = 
      closestPoint[MousePosition["Graphics", Graphics], nodeCoord, 
       snap];
     new = tail \[DirectedEdge] head;
     If[head =!= {} \[And] UnsameQ @@ new \[And] 
       FreeQ[edgeList, new] \[And] FreeQ[edgeList, Reverse@new], 
      edgeList = AppendTo[edgeList, new]]];
   deselectEdge[] := (snapEdge[]; arrowUp = False; 
     tail = tailCoord = headCoord = {});
   deleteEdge[
     edge_] := (edgeList = Delete[edgeList, firstPosition[edgeList, edge]]);
   reverseEdge[edge_] := (edgeList = edgeList /. edge -> Reverse@edge);

   selectNode[node_] := (selectedNode = node; 
     nodePos = firstPosition[First /@ nodeCoord, node]);
   moveNode[] := (If[selectedNode =!= {}, 
      nodeCoord[[nodePos, 2]] = MousePosition["Graphics", Graphics]]);
   deselectNode[] := (selectedNode = nodePos = {});
   deleteNode[n_] := If[nodes > 0,
     nodes = nodes - 1;
     nodeList = DeleteCases[nodeList, n];
     edgeList = DeleteCases[edgeList, _?(MemberQ[#, n] &)];
     nodeCoord = DeleteCases[nodeCoord, _[n, _]];
     ];
   addNode[] := If[nodes < $MaxNodes, Block[{new},
      nodes = nodes + 1;
      new = Min@Complement[Range@$MaxNodes, nodeList];
      nodeList = Append[nodeList, new];
      nodeCoord = Append[nodeCoord, new -> RandomReal[range, 2]];
      ]];

   reset[] := (
     selectedEdge = selectedNode = {};
     labels = 
      Thread[Range@$MaxNodes -> 
        Take[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], $MaxNodes]];
     update@defNodes;
     );

   update[n_] := (
     nodes = n;
     nodeList = Range@nodes;
     nodeCoord = Thread[nodeList -> circleLayout@nodes];
     edgeList = {};
     );

   reset[];

   )]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great answer (+1). Is it possible to recover (or paste) the undirected graph?

Comment: @samwolfe You can insert `Button["Copy graph", 
 CopyToClipboard@Graph[nodeList, edgeList, VertexCoordinates -> nodeCoord]]` into the top button bar of the code and when pushed, it'll copy the actual graph to the clipboard. Is this what you wanted? (Disclaimer: this code is very old with some known bugs and limitations.)

Comment: Thank you @Istvan. If you can, I started a follow-up question based on your answer, please take a look: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216495/interactive-graph-construction

Answer (score 9):

[IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) 0.6 includes `IGGraphEditor[]`, an interactive editor for creating graphs. Here's an example of it in use:

[image]

This project is still in experimental stage, and all feedback is welcome! See the documentation on how to use this function. In short, Alt-click (Command-click on Mac) is used to create/delete vertices, or to delete edges.

Big thanks to [@Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) for programming this!

Comment: This is a very, very handy feature. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a very quick and dirty solution which takes advantage of the new molecule editor just recently added in 12.2

```
MoleculeGraph[MoleculeDraw[]]
```

To make a graph, you can simply make a "molecule" where all of the atoms are vertices and all of the bonds are edges. And then use the built in MoleculeGraph function to convert it into a graph. Here's an example:

[image: Graph in MoleculeDraw]

[image: Resulting Graph]

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps Something like this:

```
Manipulate[
 Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}, VertexCoordinates -> {p1, p2, p3}, 
  PlotRange -> 1], 
 {{p1, {1, 1}}, Locator},
 {{p2, {0, 1}}, Locator},
 {{p3, {1, 0}}, Locator}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

A little more general:

```
k =  RandomGraph@{10, 10};
vc = AbsoluteOptions[k, VertexCoordinates] /. HoldPattern[_ -> l_] -> l;

DynamicModule[{pt = vc}, {LocatorPane[Dynamic@pt, 
                                      Dynamic[Subgraph[k, Range@VertexCount@k, 
                                                       VertexCoordinates -> pt]]]}]
```