# Is it possible to manipulate graphs by hand?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating graphs interactively (GUI)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2715/generating-graphs-interactively-gui)

If I plot a graph, is it possible for me to manipulate the vertices such that when I move them, their attached edges will follow.

One option that I tried is to change the graph into a graphics object, but then the edges and vertices lose their sense of being connected to each other.