# Is it possible to visually edit a graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Given a graph, obtained by something like `CompleteGraph[5]`, can I somehow add/remove edges/vertices visually? Or is the only alternative to transform it via `AdjacencyMatrix` and then transform back via `AdjacencyGraph`?

If so, is there at least a way to label the vertices in the adjacency matrix (and in the drawn graph), so that I can see which ones I'm changing?

Comment: related topic: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2715/generating-graphs-interactively-gui?rq=1

Comment: Another related topic where you create a graph and then use dynamic to add nodes: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31014/how-to-add-new-nodes-to-an-existing-graph-with-fixed-coordinates-nodes

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit extra as there is the sidebar having the commented urls linked but they may get deleted if the comments deleted so gathering all useful material in comments below.

**Relevant topics**

- [Generating graphs interactively with GUI in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2715/generating-graphs-interactively-gui)
- [How to add new nodes to an existing graph with fixed (coordinates) nodes?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31014/how-to-add-new-nodes-to-an-existing-graph-with-fixed-coordinates-nodes)

**Dupes**

- [Possible to manipulate graphs by hand](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4175/is-it-possible-to-manipulate-graphs-by-hand?lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

This might be deprecated functionality, but it used to work:

```
<< GraphUtilities`    
GraphEdit[]
```