# Enhancing GraphUtilities' GraphEdit

Tags: graphs-and-networks

One thing I use *Mathematica* for is building molecular graphs.

Until now, I've been content with generating an adjacency matrix from SMILES data, and passing that to `AdjacencyGraph`. That works well for small cyclic graphs, but the method fails my expectations when the molecules are polycyclic. I want all the edges to be of unit length, but none of the `GraphLayout` option values permit that.

[image: Undesired layout]

**GraphEdit**

The [`GraphUtilities`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/GraphUtilities/tutorial/GraphUtilities.html) package contains an [interactive graphing function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/GraphUtilities/ref/GraphEdit.html). It enables one to draw any graph, and outputs the relevant data to reconstructing it.

It would be of great help if I could pre-define graphs for `GraphEdit` to use, that could be copied any number of times inside the applet, while retaining their shapes. This screenshot (from [*ChemDraw*](http://www.cambridgesoft.com/Ensemble_for_Chemistry/ChemDraw/)) illustrates what I'm looking for:

[image]

Also, directly passing a `Graph` object to `GraphEdit` doesn't work:

```
GraphEdit[CycleGraph[6]]

(* GraphEdit[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
    4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 6 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}] *)
```

Can I add such functionality to `GraphEdit`?

Comment: Actually enhancing the applet might be very much overkill. I'm a bit confused that, while `Head@CycleGraph` is `Graph`, `GraphEdit` doesn't accept it.

Comment: Could you please put back part of the code that you had originally? Then my answer will make more sense for others. I will also be able to add more details in my answer.

Comment: I think it would be quite an elaborate task to modify `GraphEdit`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

This question may give you a good general direction:

[**Generating graphs interactively (GUI)**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2715)

**Part 1: `GraphEdit`**

Use `Rule` to pass graphs to `GraphEdit`:

```
gr = Rule @@@ Partition[Range[6], 2, 1, 1]
```

> {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 6, 6 -> 1}

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]
GraphEdit[gr]
```

[image]

`AdjacencyGraph` is a new graph functionality added in version 8. It has the whole new data format that older `GraphEdit` function cannot understand. You have to use `Rule` to pass a graph to `GraphEdit`, instead of `UndirectedEdge` or other objects associated with or produced by `Graph`, such as `CycleGraph`.

**Part 2: programmatic drawing**

You can code perfect linked polygons in this way:

```
h[x_, y_] := Polygon[Table[{Cos[2 Pi k/6] + x, Sin[2 Pi k/6] + y}, {k, 6}]]

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Opacity[.7]], LightBlue, 
  Table[h[3 i + 3 ((-1)^j + 1)/4, Sqrt[3]/2 j], {i, 5}, {j, 2}]}]
```

[image]

**Part 3: interactive drawing and copying**

If your ultimate goal is draw, copy and move polygonal objects, then maybe  [**Drawing Tools palette**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/InteractiveGraphicsPalette.html) can help? Have you seen [**this video**](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/enhanced-illustration-and-drawing-tools/draw-and-style-graphics-by-hand.html) ?

[image]

Comment: The question you linked to is mine ;) Indeed, Heike's answer is very nice, and I do use it in my notebooks. I was wondering if adding a button or two to `GraphEdit` was at all possible, since it might be a more general, less ad-hoc, way of solving the problem. Thanks for the tips.