# Manually adjust graph vertex location by dragging?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, output-formatting

Sometimes I have a graph and I want to make tweaks to the vertex locations. Is there any way to manually adjust graph vertex location by dragging?

If I double click to edit, I can move around the vertex rendered shape (square) or the label inside the square, but not the vertex itself. Also, even if I could move the vertex, it is under the rendered square/circle which does not seem to move with it.

I have been using `GraphPlot`. (Should I be using `Graph` instead? I don't really understand the difference.):

```
GraphPlot[Import["D:/dev/ProjectEuler/keylog.gv"], 
 VertexLabeling -> True, PlotStyle -> {Black}, 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Black], White, Disk[#1, 0.08], 
     Black, Text[#2, #1]} &)]
```

Comment: Highly related (if not duplicate): [Manipulate Graphs](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2715/89).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the locations of the vertices by double clicking on them and dragging. For example:

```
GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 1}]
```

[image]

After double clicking and dragging two of the vertices:

[image]

If you have labels and ornaments on the vertices, then you can move them independently. For example, after moving two of the circles, numbered labels, and vertices:

```
GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 1}, PlotStyle -> {Black}, 
VertexRenderingFunction->({EdgeForm[Black],White,Disk[#1, 0.08],Black,Text[#2,#1]} &)]
```

[image]

Comment: How do I do deal with the situation that there is a rendered label on top of the vertex?

Comment: How are you rendering the label?

Comment: I have updated the post to show the rendering code.

Comment: I guess the answer is the same: you can move the labels independently of the vertices, the circles, and the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You may try:

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]
GraphEdit[Table[i -> Mod[i^3, 27], {i, 0, 27}]]
```