# VertexRenderingFunction (or EdgeRenderingFunction) with movable nodes?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, interactive

In GraphPlot, I'd like to use VertexRenderingFunction (VRF) and have the resulting object behave the same way under dragging verticies as it does when I do not use VRF. The same issue occurs for EdgeRenderingFunction (ERF) and dragging edges.

Here's a MWE:

```
g = {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1};
{
  GraphPlot[g]
  ,
  GraphPlot[g, VertexRenderingFunction -> ({Blue, Disk[#1, 0.01]} &)]
}
```

Without VRF, I can click (sufficiently many times) on a node, drag it around, and the graph deforms without losing connections between the node and edges - see element one in the picture below. With VRF, if I click on a node, it behaves like a distinct graphics object that does not maintain connectivity to the appropriate edges - element two in the picture. [image: The problem.]

I'm guessing this has to do with how Mathematica generates the graphs since their InputForms are different:

```
 InputForm[GraphPlot[g]]

 (*Graphics[Annotation[GraphicsComplex[{{0., 0.9997532360813222}, 
 {0.9993931236462025, 1.0258160108662504}, {1.0286626995939243, 
 0.026431169015735057}, {0.02872413637035287, 0.}}, 
 {{RGBColor[0.5, 0., 0.], Line[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}}]}, 
 {RGBColor[0, 0, 0.7], Tooltip[Point[1], 1], Tooltip[Point[2], 2], 
 Tooltip[Point[3], 3], Tooltip[Point[4], 4]}}, {}], 
 VertexCoordinateRules -> {{0., 0.9997532360813222}, 
 {0.9993931236462025, 1.0258160108662504}, {1.0286626995939243, 
 0.026431169015735057}, {0.02872413637035287, 0.}}], 
 FrameTicks -> None, PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> 
 Scaled[0.1], AspectRatio -> Automatic]*)
```

vs.

```
In[159]:= InputForm[GraphPlot[g, VertexRenderingFunction -> ({Blue, Disk[#1, 0.01]} &)]]

(* Out[159]//InputForm=
Graphics[Annotation[GraphicsGroup[
{GraphicsComplex[{{0., 0.9997532360813222}, {0.9993931236462025, 
1.0258160108662504}, {1.0286626995939243, 0.026431169015735057}, 
{0.02872413637035287, 0.}}, {RGBColor[0.5, 0., 0.], 
Line[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}}]}, {}], 
{{RGBColor[0, 0, 1], Disk[{0., 0.9997532360813222}, 0.01]}, 
{RGBColor[0, 0, 1], Disk[{0.9993931236462025, 
1.0258160108662504}, 0.01]}, {RGBColor[0, 0, 1], 
Disk[{1.0286626995939243, 0.026431169015735057}, 0.01]}, 
{RGBColor[0, 0, 1], Disk[{0.02872413637035287, 0.}, 0.01]}}}, 
ContentSelectable -> True], VertexCoordinateRules -> {{0., 
0.9997532360813222}, {0.9993931236462025, 1.0258160108662504}, 
{1.0286626995939243, 0.026431169015735057}, {0.02872413637035287, 
0.}}], FrameTicks -> None, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1], AspectRatio -> Automatic]*)
```

I'm interested in this because I want to draw more complicated graphs with a subset of vertices styled one way, another subset styled a different way, and so on. In [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38561/manually-adjust-graph-vertex-location-by-dragging), someone suggested just dragging around the rendered vertices after moving the edges, but:

- This option is not feasible for more than a handful of verticies, especially if the verticies are supposed to be labeled in special ways.
- If I want to use both ERF and VRF, then I have to move every piece of the graph individually.
- It seems if Mathematica creates the non-VRF graphs in a way I like, then I should be able to duplicate the behavior on my own VRF, but I couldn't work out how from the InputForms.
- The ability to click and drag edges is important because Mathematica does not render graphs the way I want them to appear (even under various "Methods->___"). So any solutions with different graph options (i.e. using Graph) should also offer a way to arbitrarily deform the output graph.

Comment: Please see the abstraction `withVRF` that I added.

Comment: I edited the title in an effort to make it more concise and descriptive; I hope you do not mind.

Comment: Fine with me. And your solution worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the vertices to be correctly movable their primitives must be positioned using the indexes of [`GraphicsComplex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsComplex.html) rather than direct `Graphics` coordinates.  This way all primitives with the same index move together.  I don't know of a way to make `VertexRenderingFunction` use these indexes natively, though I have not explored it.  However since the default vertex points are created within the `GraphicsComplex` we can apply the vertex function in post-processing to achieve your goal:

```
g = {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1};

GraphPlot[g] /. Point[n_Integer] :> {Blue, Disk[n, 0.1]}
```

[image]

If you wish to use vertex labels you will need a slightly different replacement:

```
GraphPlot[g] /. 
  Tooltip[Point[n_Integer], label_] :>
    {Blue, Disk[n, 0.1], White, Text[label ~Style~ 18, n]}
```

[image]

If you already have your `VertexRenderingFunction` written here is an abstraction:

```
withVRF[VRF_][args__] := GraphPlot[args] /.
      Tooltip[Point[n_Integer], label_] :> VRF[n, label]
```

Example:

```
vertex = {White, EdgeForm[Black], Disk[#, .1], Black, Text[#2, #1]} &;

withVRF[vertex][g, DirectedEdges -> True]
```

[image]