# How to make the vertices move with the VertexRenderingFunction graphics when clicking and dragging vertices of a layered graph

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

I have read the suggested similar question here:

[VertexRenderingFunction (or EdgeRenderingFunction) with movable nodes?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75712/vertexrenderingfunction-or-edgerenderingfunction-with-movable-nodes)

and Mr. Wizard's solution.
Please could someone help me to apply his method to my example:

[image: graphexample]

My code is below.
I would like the vertices of the graph to move with the pictures of the grids, when I click and drag the grids around.

```
arraydims = {2, 2};
cases = Tuples[{False, True}, arraydims];
elementsum[array_] := Total[Flatten[array]];
directsuccesorQ[case1_, case2_] := If[
   And[
    Total[
      Boole[MapThread[#1 =!= #2 &, {Flatten[case1], 
         Flatten[case2]}]]] == 1,
    elementsum[Boole[Flatten[case1, 1]]] < 
     elementsum[Boole[Flatten[case2, 1]]]
    ],
   True, False];
plotsystem[array_] := 
  MatrixPlot[array, ColorRules -> {False -> White, True -> Black}, 
   Mesh -> True, Frame -> False, FrameTicks -> False, ImageSize -> 20];
adjacencymatrix = 
  Table[Boole[directsuccesorQ[cases[[i]], cases[[j]]]], {i, 1, 
    Length[cases]}, {j, 1, Length[cases]}];
G = AdjacencyGraph[adjacencymatrix];
LayeredGraphPlot[G, 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> (Inset[plotsystem[cases[[#2]]], #] &), 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

Comment: Simply replace `GraphPlot` with `LayeredGraphPlot` in the definition of `withVRF` and it works as written.  I am closing this as a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, @Mr.Wizard. In fact I tried replacing GraphPlot with LayeredGraphPlot in your other answer, in the definition of withVRF. That worked very well, but the vertex pictures were your circles with numbers inside, whereas I would like them to be the little grids generated by my function "plotsystem" above. I tried but failed to replace your circles with my plotsystem command. Any help you could give me with that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you again for all your input.

Comment: You still need to use *your* vertex rendering function.  Evaluate the code in your post, then: `fn = Inset[plotsystem[cases[[#2]]], #] &;
LayeredGraphPlot[G, ImageSize -> Large] /.
 Tooltip[Point[n_Integer], label_] :> fn[n, label]`.  Or define:  `withVRFlayered[VRF_][args__] := 
 LayeredGraphPlot[args] /. Tooltip[Point[n_Integer], label_] :> VRF[n, label]` and then use:  `withVRFlayered[Inset[plotsystem[cases[[#2]]], #] &][G, ImageSize -> Large]`

Comment: Thank you so much @Mr.Wizard ! Sorry to seem idle. In fact I tried hard to implement your code with my function, but failed. I really appreciate you helping me out !

Comment: It's okay, and you're welcome.  As I have said to many before you I wouldn't be here if I didn't wish to help.