# Manually moving a vertex with a label by dragging in GraphPlot (v12.0)

Tags: graphs-and-networks

How can I manually adjust the position of a vertex with a label by dragging within GraphPlot?

I am using Mathematica 12.0. Dragging works fine with vertex-unlabeled graphs, e.g.

```
GraphPlot[{"1" -> "2", "1" -> "3", "2" -> "3"}]
```

however, when I add vertex labels

```
GraphPlot[{"1" -> "2", "1" -> "3", "2" -> "3"}, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

I can only move the circle representing the vertex, without moving the vertex itself. When I try to move the actual point, it just disconnects one of the incident edges and moves that edge around.

The same question was asked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38561/68548), however I can't get the offered solution to work in 12.0 either (and it uses the outdated VertexRenderingFunction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In versions 12.0+, you can access the legacy `GraphPlot` functionality using

```
GraphComputation`GraphPlotLegacy[{"1" -> "2", "1" -> "3", "2" -> "3"},
   VertexLabeling -> True]
```

Comment: Hi @kglr, how did you find this?

Comment: Victor, with major v12 changes in `GraphPlot`  I thought  old `GraphPlot` should be accessible somehow for backward compatibility...  and I tried ``Names["*`*raphPlot*"]``

Comment: Thanks, that’s pretty smart.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. Any thoughts on why in 12.0+ dragging labelled vertices works like it does? Is it a bug or a feature?