# Detect a graphic primitive inside a Graphic

Tags: graphics, eventhandler

Please excuse me if that question is too basic but I couldn't find anything in the documentation or on here.

If you consider the following `Graphic` I would like to know how to detect which primitive is being clicked,

```
Graphics[{Disk[#, 0.5]} & /@ {{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]
```

[image]

and for example change the color of the clicked `Disk`, change its radius or get the coordinates of its center or anything related to its geometry.

I am aware that [`EventHandler`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EventHandler.html) is my friend but as the questions states, I have no clue how to detect which primitive is being clicked (except by using [`Mouseposition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Mouseposition.html) and compare it to the centers).

I am also aware that my question is somehow poorly researched but I feel like I'm blocking on a basic notion.

Comment: The way to do this is by using `EventHandler` and `Dynamic` color on each primitive that you want to track. I don't think you can develop a robust solution (or maybe near impossible) by using just one outer `EventHandler` and infer which primitive is being clicked. So, in this case, it's just the same as the example under "Scope" in the doc page you linked to.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6189751/615464

Comment: @rm-rf In [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2746/1356) István Zachar is kinda doing it (opening a menu on the clicked node), but I can not find the way to extract the interesting pieces of code.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries A pity we can't migrate that one

Comment: @belisarius I could cheat and just copy the answer...

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries it is interesting regarding the coloring changes indeed. But is it possible to extract primitives values (like radius or center) from a clicked object?

Comment: @Öskå Yes, of course. This is easy, since you define an event handler for every object and for each event.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries If you do, ping me and I'll delete mine here

Comment: @belisarius I guess it's OK to have your version here. A straight copy wouldn't add much beyond what's already there. BTW I'm still amazed that it works for 3D too. I wonder how well this scales for tens of objects though.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries  Please do just copy the answer.  Blocked migrations means that is the only way to gather information here, on our site and under our control.

Comment: @belisarius done. Added some code to test scalability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[EventHandler](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EventHandler.html) can be used to catch various mouse events (mouse up, mouse down, mouse clicked, mouse dragged). Use MousePosition to add some intelligence.

Example:

```
DynamicModule[{col1 = Green, col2 = Blue}, Graphics[
  {
   EventHandler[
    Dynamic[{col1, Disk[]}, 
     ImageSize -> 
      Tiny], {"MouseClicked" :> (col1 = 
        col1 /. {Red -> Green, Green -> Red})}],
   EventHandler[
    Dynamic[{col2, Disk[{1, 1}]}, 
     ImageSize -> 
      Tiny], {"MouseClicked" :> (col2 = 
        col2 /. {Blue -> Yellow, Yellow -> Blue})}]
   }
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

The circles can be clicked independently. An action is defined for each object separately.

Amazingly, this even works for 3D Graphics:

```
DynamicModule[{col1 = Green, col2 = Blue}, 
 Graphics3D[
  {
   EventHandler[
    Dynamic[{col1, Sphere[]}, 
     ImageSize -> 
      Tiny], {"MouseClicked" :> (col1 = 
        col1 /. {Red -> Green, Green -> Red})}], 
   EventHandler[
    Dynamic[{col2, Sphere[{1, 1, 1}]}, 
     ImageSize -> 
      Tiny], {"MouseClicked" :> (col2 = 
        col2 /. {Blue -> Yellow, Yellow -> Blue})}]
   }
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Here's some code to test the scalability:

```
With[{n = 100},
 DynamicModule[{col = RGBColor @@@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 3}]},
  Graphics[
   Table[
    With[{j = i},
     EventHandler[
      {Dynamic[col[[j]]], Disk[RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {2}]]}, 
      ImageSize -> Tiny,
      {"MouseClicked" :> (col[[j]] = 
          RGBColor @@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3}])}
      ]
     ], {i, n}
    ]
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is reasonably responsive. However, try the version with n=1000:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

On my PC the color changes only after about three seconds. So, if you need to interact with many objects this may not be the best solution.

Comment: Would you know by any chance how to extract the radius or "physical" information? Your last update is really great & interesting.

Comment: @Öskå Since all of the information to draw the object in the `EventHandler` is to be found there you probably can communicate this by means of the event action, for instance, by having it set a global variable or so. In the example below the action could be extended from `(col[[j]] = RGBColor @@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3}])` to `(clickedColor=col[[j]] = RGBColor @@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3}])`