# Why the Mouse dragging response not as smooth as Locator

Tags: graphs-and-networks, dynamic, eventhandler

I am experimenting to use `MouseDragged` eventhandler to change the vertices positions of a triangle, it works, but not as smooth as using Locators. Is this the correct way to handle mouse dragging? Would someone please help to improve the response speed.

```
DynamicModule[{ pos1 = {1, 0}/2 , pos2 = {1, 1}/2 , pos3 = {-1, 0}/2},
 edglst = { 1 <-> 2 , 2 <-> 3 , 3 <-> 1   };
  Dynamic@Graph[
   { EventHandler[1, {"MouseDragged" :> (pos1 = MousePosition["Graphics"])}],
     EventHandler[2, {"MouseDragged" :> (pos2 = MousePosition["Graphics"])}], 
     EventHandler[3, {"MouseDragged" :> (pos3 = MousePosition["Graphics"])}]} ,
   edglst,
   VertexCoordinates -> {pos1, pos2, pos3 } ,
   VertexSize -> 0.08, VertexLabels -> "Name",
   PlotRange -> 1, EdgeStyle -> {Thick}, ImagePadding -> 10]]
```

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2715/7167)

Comment: It works quite smooth for me, the problem is that it loses the focus, isn't it?

Comment: @Kuba. what you report is my experience, too.

Comment: This is a tough problem. I've made some minor improvements to the OP's code, but nothing dramatic enough to be worth posting. I *have* found, after playing with this problem for a while, that my dragging skills have improved to the point where I only infrequently loose a vertex as I drag it around.

Comment: The vertex does follow the mouse nicely if the mouse motion is slow enough, but the vertex just stop behind when the mouse moves in normal speed. Locator doesn't have such problem.

Comment: It might be helpful if you were to add the locator version of your code to your question. I, for one, would like to see how it differs from the currently posted code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is that as soon as the cursor gets away from a particular vertex marker it leaves the associated `EventHandler`.

Here's a work-around, let's associate the event handler with the whole `Graph`. We just need to take care of updating the proper `pos`.

```
 DynamicModule[{ind = 1, pos1 = {1, 0}/2, pos2 = {1, 1}/2, pos3 = {-1, 0}/2},
                   edglst = {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1};
 EventHandler[
  Dynamic @ Graph[{1, 2, 3}, edglst, VertexCoordinates -> {pos1, pos2, pos3}, 
                  VertexSize -> 0.08, VertexLabels -> "Name", PlotRange -> 1, 
                  EdgeStyle -> {Thick}, ImagePadding -> 10, Frame -> True],

  {"MouseDown" :> With[{set = {pos1, pos2, pos3}, pos = MousePosition["Graphics"]},
                       ind = Position[set, Nearest[set, pos][[1]]][[1, 1]]],       
   "MouseDragged" :> (ReleaseHold[Hold[Set][Hold[{pos1, pos2, pos3}][[{1}, ind]], 
                                            MousePosition["Graphics"]]])},
   PassEventsDown -> True]]
```

[image]

Notice that inner `EventHandlers` are not needed now but you can add them with any additional procedures you need. For this purpose I've left `PassEventsDown-True`.

Comment: That's way better ;)

Comment: Well done. I messed with this for some time, but failed to come up with anything nearly so good as this.

Comment: And further, I would call this a solution, not a work-around (or a "walk-around" as you call it :).

Comment: @Kuba It is really cool, thanks a lot! But it is hard for me to see through the tricks behind the code:"MouseDragged" :> (
  ReleaseHold[
   Hold[Set]
    [
    Hold[{pos1, pos2, pos3}][[  {1}, ind   ]],
     MousePosition["Graphics"]
    ](* Hold *)
   ](* ReleaseHold *)
  ) Would you please give some explanations on it?

Comment: @m_goldberg You are probably right, thanks for the edit. :)

Comment: @user16069 we are creating expression: `posX = MousePos[..]` but we can't allow `posX` to evaluate. We are doing this with two ticks, take a look what `{}` are doing within `[[]]`: with `a = 1; Hold[{a}][[{1}, 1]]` and without `Hold[{a}][[1, 1]]`. The second trick is just strightforward `Hold` on `Set` to the very end.

Comment: @user16069. I have posted a modification of Kuba's answer that addressed your issues with all the `Hold`, `ReleaseHold` stuff.

Comment: @Kuba I get it now, the "{1}" is referring to the holding list. Thanks.

Comment: @user16069 Yes, and `{}` are important because they are preserving outer `Head` which is `Hold` here, without those you'd get `1` like in the second example I've provided.

Answer (score 7):

Kuba's answer is brilliant, but it has a rather ugly bit in it with a lot of unnecessary fooling around with `Hold` and `ReleaseHold` in order to make assignment to variables. As is so often the case with *Mathematica*, this fooling around with variables can be eliminated by working with a list, so I have reworked Kuba's  answer to keep the vertex coordinates in a list. That makes the mouse drag action simple because there in no need make assignments to variables.

```
DynamicModule[{index = 1, vertxCoords = {{1., 0.}/2, {1., 1.}/2, {-1., 0.}/2}},
  EventHandler[
    Dynamic@Graph[{1, 2, 3}, {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, 
      VertexCoordinates -> vertxCoords,
      VertexSize -> {.04, .04},
      VertexLabels -> "Name",
      PlotRange -> 1,
      EdgeStyle -> Thick,
      ImagePadding -> 10,
      Frame -> True],
    {"MouseDown" :>
      With[{p = MousePosition["Graphics"]}, 
        index = Position[vertxCoords, Nearest[vertxCoords, p][[1]]][[1, 1]]], 
     "MouseDragged" :> (vertxCoords[[index]] = MousePosition["Graphics"])},
    PassEventsDown -> True]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So the reason for this problem is because of getting lost of focus as pointed out by Kuba previously. And it is not a good practice to set the Eventhandlers on the tiny individual vertices on this purpose.