# Use the mouse to pinch the plasticine

Tags: dynamic, demonstrations

Very roughly speaking, a topological space is a geometric object, and the homeomorphism is a continuous stretching and bending of the object into a new shape. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism)

[image: A continuous deformation between a coffee mug and a donut (torus) illustrating that they are homeomorphic.]

> A continuous deformation between a coffee mug and a donut (torus)
> illustrating that they are homeomorphic.

I tried to demonstrate homeomorphic operations about sphere or torus.

Does mathematica or other software have a ready-made package to demonstrate the homeomorphic operation of the surface?  It is best to **use the mouse** to demonstrate the surface arbitrary continuous torsion process. It's like playing with silly putty. The process may be **irregular or arbitrary**. Note that the change trajectory of the above animation has certain rules. This has some limitations on display.

The production of dynamic layout of graph which was seen as a One-dimensional topological space in graph theory seems to be similar to my idea.

- [Why the Mouse dragging response not as smooth as Locator](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51369/why-the-mouse-dragging-response-not-as-smooth-as-locator?rq=1)

Comment: This [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6061/9469) might be relevant.

Comment: @yarchik Thank you. It's relevant. I'll read it.