# Exclude data from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics, plotting

Let's create some random sample data

```
data = Table[{RandomReal[{-10, 10}], RandomReal[{-10, 10}]}, {i, 1, 300}];
```

Then we plot them using `ListPlot`

```
L0 = ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

And here is the output

[image]

Now, how can I select from the screen plot some date (those inside the red closed regions) using the mouse and then delete them form the list, thus creating a new list (data1)? Note here, that we don't know the equations of the red closed regions; they are completely arbitrary.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your application? Would an `Epilog` that drew white shapes on top of the points you wanted to "delete" suffice?

Comment: @Verbeia Just white space is not enough. I want to have the new list `data1` (without the excluded points) ready for further manipulation.

Comment: Ok, then I don't have time to work it out now (bedtime in Australia) but you probably do actually need some kind of equation for each regions, and then use `DeleteCases` to remove the points.

Comment: I'm afraid that there are no known equations for these regions. They have to be selected by hand using the mouse to define the closed area. Anyway, if for example we wanted to exclude all data inside the circle of radius 1 how would we use `DeleteCases`?

Comment: yes, this can be done, but not trivial. The first stage, is to select the points using the mouse. How would a complete region be determined to have been selected? What if the users does not close the circle around? How to decide if the free hand drawn circle is closed, how about if user decided to change and clear the region, etc.. there are many use cases issues to be decided first, ie. design stage, before even thinking of the implementation. An easier way to do it, would be to use the mouse to click on 2 places, and that will make a square with these as 2 corners. This is much easier.

Comment: @Nasser I see your points. Then let's start from something easy. How would we delete all points from the list which are inside a circle with center at (1,2) and radius 2?

Comment: @ Nasser: I know the command Input[] where the application waits for text Input and then continues. But I didn't know that a "graphic" interaction where the application waits for a mouse click is possible in MMA. What object (picture, plot) do you click on? How are the coordinates transferred to the MMA program?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze  Using the Mouse functions, such as  `MousePosition["Graphics"]` and related. There are few demos on WRI that uses mouse to obtain coordinates from plot. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MousePosition.html  but for this problem, one need to map the coordinates of the graphics, to the actual points in the data as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
data = Table[{RandomReal[{-10, 10}], RandomReal[{-10, 10}]}, {i, 1, 300}]; 
L0 = ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  ImageSize -> 400, BaseStyle -> PointSize[.02]];
```

Using @rm-rf's  function `inPolyQ`

```
inPolyQ[poly_, pt_] := Graphics`Mesh`PointWindingNumber[poly, pt] =!= 0
```

from [this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9417/125):

```
Deploy@ DynamicModule[{list = {}}, 
   Row[{EventHandler[Dynamic[Show[L0, Graphics[{Opacity[.7], Yellow, EdgeForm[Thick], 
                      Polygon[list], Purple, PointSize[.03], Point[list]}, 
                      PlotRange -> PlotRange[L0]]]],
          {"MouseDragged" :>  AppendTo[list, MousePosition["Graphics"]]}], 
       Dynamic@ListPlot[If[Length@list <= 2, data, 
                      Style[#, If[inPolyQ[list, #], Red, Blue]] & /@ data], 
                      BaseStyle -> PointSize[.02], Axes -> False, L0[[2]], 
               Prolog -> {Opacity[.5], Yellow, Polygon[list]}]}, Spacer[5]]]
```

[image]

Change the first argument of `ListPlot` to

```
If[Length@list <= 2, data, Pick[data, ! inPolyQ[list, #] & /@ data]]
```

to delete the points inside the selected polygon:

[image]

Note: As is, this can handle a single polygon. With some additional effort, it should be possible to handle multiple separate polygons.

Comment: On v10's you can replace `inPolyQ` with `Element`, with accepts a great deal of "regions" (besides Polygons, of course)!

Comment: @Aisamu, good point; V10 has a number new functions that could be useful for the current task.. (I am still on v9 and the free Wolfram Programming Cloud is not too convenient to use:).

Comment: As it turns out, there is even another, **much** faster function: `RegionMember`!

Comment: @Aisamu, yes, i was aware of `RegionMember`; but, as i mentioned, it is a pain to use the free cloud version. Perhaps, you might consider posting an answer using `RegionMember`?

Comment: I just did, but on the Q/A you mentioned. You answer has more than properly covered OP's concerns!

Comment: Your inPolyQ test does not work in version 11 or 12. It should be replaced with:
Graphics`PolygonUtils`PointWindingNumber, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9417/45020.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a very simple example of a circular "eraser" which you can move around with the mouse and adjust the radius with a slider. Then click the button to remove points within the circle from `data`.

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}, r = 3}, Column[{
   Slider[Dynamic[r], {0.1, 5}],
   Button["Delete", data = Select[data, EuclideanDistance[#, pt] > r &]],
   LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt],
    Dynamic[ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, 
      Epilog -> Circle[pt, r], ImageSize -> 300]], 
    Appearance -> None]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I know it doesn't really answers the question (since it doesn't use a region or anything else) but you could do the following (which is based on [that](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2746/1356)) to delete the points you wish to delete:

```
DynamicModule[{range = {-10, 10}, defpts = 100, pts, ptList = None, 
  ptCoord, selectedpt, ptPos, reset, create, selectpt, deselectpt, 
  deletept, firstPosition, export},
 firstPosition[list_, case_] := Position[list, case, 1, 1][[1, 1]];
 Panel@Column@{Button["Export Current data", export[], ImageSize -> 400],
    Panel[Graphics[{Dynamic[({EventHandler[{Dynamic[{If[selectedpt === #, 
                 deletept@selectedpt], Point[# /. ptCoord]}, 
               TrackedSymbols :> {selectedpt, ptCoord}]}, 
             {{"MouseDown", 1} :> (selectedpt = #;),
              {"MouseUp", 1} :> (selectedpt = deselectpt[];)}]} & /@ 
          ptList), TrackedSymbols :> {ptList}]}
      , PlotRange -> {range, range}, Frame -> True, 
      Background -> White], ImageSize -> 400, Background -> White]},
 Initialization :> (
   export[] := Export["~/test.dat", Last /@ ptCoord];
   selectpt[pt_] := (selectedpt = pt; ptPos = firstPosition[First /@ ptCoord, pt]);
   deselectpt[] := (selectedpt = ptPos = {});
   deletept[n_] := If[pts > 0, pts = pts - 1;
     ptList = DeleteCases[ptList, n];
     ptCoord = DeleteCases[ptCoord, _[n, _]];];
   reset[] := (selectedpt = {}; create@defpts;);
   create[n_] := (pts = n; ptList = Range@pts;
     ptCoord = Thread[ptList -> RandomReal[range, {defpts, 2}]];);
   reset[];)]
```

[image]

By clicking on "Export Current data" you would have in my case:

```
Import["~/test.dat"] // Length
```

> ```
> 87
> ```

It is unfortunately quite slow with bigger list, if anyone knows how to speed it up please let me know :)

Comment: Dear Öskå,very good solution!
I'm wondering where in your code I can load my data...
Thanks!

Comment: @meriens Thank you :) Alas it doesn't exactly reply the question. But I found it quite handy (yet slow..). You need to load your data in the `create[n_] := (pts = n; ptList = Range@pts;
   ptCoord = Thread[ptList -> RandomReal[range, {defpts, 2}]];);` function. I use `RandomReal` here instead of a set of data.

Comment: @meriens You need to first define your data, then change `defpts = Length@data` and `ptCoord = Thread[ptList -> data]`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/OfECU.png

Answer (score 3):

Try the function `deletePoints[lst,imageSize]` given below. Its first argument is the list of points, some of which you wish to delete, the second is the size of the image that you see on the screen for the convenience of working. The function shows the list on a `LocatorPane`, and you can select the points by `Alt+LeftMouseClick`, which brings up a locator in the vicinity of the point in question. You do not need to exactly hit the point in question. It is enough to place the locator closer to this point, than to the other ones. As soon as the points are selected, press the button in the bottom of the image. This generates two global variables: `lstDeleted` and `lstSurvived`. By evaluating them you get the both lists, and may then plot them, or do whatever else.

The function:

```
 deletePoints[lst_List, imageSize_Integer] := 
  DynamicModule[{pts = {}, lstNearest},
   lstNearest[a_List, b_List] := (Nearest[a, #, 1] // First) & /@ b;
   Column[{
     Dynamic@LocatorPane[
       Dynamic[pts],
       Dynamic@ListPlot[lst, ImageSize -> imageSize],
       LocatorAutoCreate -> True, ImageSize -> imageSize
       ],
     Button["Make the lists of survived and deleted points",
      Clear[lstDeleted, lstSurvived]; 
      lstDeleted = lstNearest[lst, pts];
      lstSurvived = 
       Delete[lst, First /@ (Position[lst, #] & /@ lstDeleted)]
      ]
     }]];
```

Example of its functioning. Let this be a list in question:

```
    lst = RandomReal[{-10, 5}, {10, 2}]

  (*  {{4.20383, -2.58995}, {-0.928284, -4.00225}, {1.61195, -9.17291},{-1.58935, 
      0.338292}, {-0.719281, -7.70116}, {-1.93687, -1.35842}, {-3.26784,-2.04274}, {-8.16471, -4.36758}, {-0.585342, -6.41022}, {-7.04512, 1.20394}}  *)
```

Apply the function:

```
deletePoints[lst, 400]
```

and select few points. I selected three that you can see in the image below. Press the button and evaluate the variables:

```
    lstSurvived
lstDeleted

(*  {{4.20383, -2.58995}, {1.61195, -9.17291}, {-1.58935, 
  0.338292}, {-0.719281, -7.70116}, {-3.26784, -2.04274}, {-0.585342,-6.41022}, {-7.04512, 1.20394}}

{{-0.928284, -4.00225}, {-1.93687, -1.35842}, {-8.16471, -4.36758}}  *)
```

[image]

Have fun!