# FindRoot with Inequality on Co-domain?

Tags: equation-solving, functions

I'm hoping to implement a `FindRoot` procedure with an inequality constraint.  However, I'm hopelessly confused at this point, because the inequality doesn't constrain the domain region, but rather constrains the co-domain.  In other words, I have an inequality on the co-domain, and I only want to find roots mapping into this region!  I'm hoping for some tips on how to make this work smoothly.  My lengthy preamble is:

```
M = 1;
tau = (0.4) + (0.5)*I;
w1 = Pi/2;
w2 = Pi*(tau)/2;
inv = WeierstrassInvariants[{w1, w2}];
E2[t_] := 
  1 - 24*Sum[(n*Exp[2*Pi*I*(t)*n])/(1 - Exp[2*Pi*I*(t)*n]), {n, 1, 
      300}];
z[u_] := (I*
     M/2)*(WeierstrassZeta[u, inv] - ((1/3)*N[E2[tau], 50]*(u)));
WP[x_, y_] := WeierstrassP[w1*x + w2*y, inv];
L = -(1/3)*N[E2[tau], 50];
f[x_, y_] := Re[WP[x, y] - L];
g[x_, y_] := Im[WP[x, y] - L];
V1 = Quiet[
   FindRoot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, 0.5}, {y, 1}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 50]];
V2 = Quiet[
   FindRoot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, 1.5}, {y, 1}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 50]];
V3 = Quiet[
   FindRoot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, 0.5}, {y, -1}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 50]];
V4 = Quiet[
   FindRoot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, 1.5}, {y, -1}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 50]];
A1 = x /. V1;
B1 = y /. V1;
A2 = x /. V2;
B2 = y /. V2;
A3 = x /. V3;
B3 = y /. V3;
A4 = x /. V4;
B4 = y /. V4;
Z1 = Quiet[N[z[w1*A1 + w2*B1], 50]]
Z2 = Quiet[N[z[w1*A2 + w2*B2], 50]]
Z3 = Quiet[N[z[w1*A3 + w2*B3], 50]]
Z4 = Quiet[N[z[w1*A4 + w2*B4], 50]]
m = (Im[Z1] - Im[Z2])/((Re[Z1] - Re[Z2]));
Zed[x_, y_] := z[w1*x + w2*y];
```

Phew, okay, so I want to implement a `FindRoot` line like

```
F1[x_] =
   FindRoot[
    Im[N[Zed[x, y]]] - (m*(Re[N[Zed[x, y] - (M/2)]]) + Im[M/2]) == 
     0, {y, 0}, WorkingPrecision -> 50];
```

Except I need the constraint that

$$\big|\rm{Zed}[x,y]-\tfrac{M}{2}\big| \leq \big|Z2-\tfrac{M}{2}\big|,$$

where $M$ and $Z2$ have been provided numerically already.  Is there a clean way to input this constraint?  Any tips would be appreciated!  Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `NSolve[]`?

Comment: @Feyre I hadn't thought of that, no.  Can you maybe show me how the syntax might go?  I recall using inequalities in `NSolve` before, but I'm still not sure how it would work in my case, where the inequality constrains the codomain.

Comment: I just tried it, but it seems to have problems with the target variable in the  `Weierstrass` where `FindRoot` doesn't. Sorry. Maybe someone else can figure it out? BTW, you're missing a `:` in your `F1` declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of a built-in function that accomplishes the goal of the question.  Nonetheless, a solution can be obtained in a fairly straightforward manner.  Incidentally, `WorkingPrecision -> 50` is unnecessary, slows the computation, and triggers numerous warning messages.  I have deleted it from the code in the question prior to the following computation.

It is helpful to start by determining where the roots and constraints lie in `{x, y}`:

```
constraints = ContourPlot[Abs[Zed[x, y] - M/2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -5, 7}, 
    Contours -> {Abs[Z2 - M/2]}, ContourShading -> {Orange, White}, ContourStyle -> None];

roots = ContourPlot[Im[N[Zed[x, y]]] - (m*(Re[N[Zed[x, y] - (M/2)]]) + Im[M/2]) == 0,
    {x, -1, 1}, {y, -5, 7}, MaxRecursion -> 4];

Show[constraints, roots]
```

The desired roots are those lying in the orange regions.  (The plot is symmetric about `{0, 1}` and periodic in `x` with period `2`.)

[image]

A suggested by [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) in a comment, `constraints` also can be obtained from

```
constraints = RegionPlot[N@Abs[Zed[x, y] - M/2] <= Abs[Z2 - M/2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -5, 7}, 
    BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotStyle -> Orange, PlotPoints -> 150]
```

The roots lying in the orange band `0.7 < y < 1.3` can be obtained by

```
F2[x_?NumericQ, g_] := FindRoot[Im[N[Zed[x, y]]] - (m*(Re[N[Zed[x, y] - M/2]]) + Im[M/2]),
   {y, g, g - .1, g + .1}]

t = ConstantArray[1, 201];
Do[t[[n]] = y /. F2[-1 + .01 (n - 1), t[[n - 1]]], {n, 2, 201}];
ListLinePlot[t, DataRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

[image]

A much smaller band lies near

```
y /. F2[.21, 3.3]
(* 3.35896 *)
```

and an infinitesimal band is barely visible at the right of the top loop.

**Addendum**

A more efficient way to plot the roots satisfying the constraints is

```
ContourPlot[Im[N[Zed[x, y]]] - (m*(Re[N[Zed[x, y] - (M/2)]]) + Im[M/2]) == 0,
    {x, -1, 1}, {y, -5, 7}, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, f}, N@Abs[Zed[x, y] - M/2] <= Abs[Z2 - M/2]]]
```

[image]

The 2714 individual roots comprising this plot can be obtained from

```
Union[%[[1, 1]]]
```

if desired. Undoubtedly, even more roots exist at larger `Abs[y]`.

Comment: Why not use `RegionPlot[]` for depicting the constraints?

Comment: @J.M.  And, the `RegionFunction` option works even better.  Your comment on `RegionPlot[]` helped me to think of it.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Wow, thank you so much!!  This is precisely what I was hoping for.  In fact, I think it does even more.  If I'm understanding correctly, the way you've done this, it would even work if that large, middle line wasn't simply a function of $x$?  In other words, even if it "curled back" on itself in certain regions, its point would still be collected into what you call t?  Thanks again, this is fabulous.

Comment: @spietro  If the curve is too complex, it might be difficult for the calculation of `t` to follow without additional refinement.  However, the method in the addendum should work under any circumstance.  Best wishes.

Comment: @bbgodfrey This works flawlessly when the curve is a function of the horizontal variable, but breaks down if the curve has multiple outputs $y$ for a given $x$.  Off the top of your head, do you have any tips on what refinements you speak of, that I might look into in this case?  I'm referring to the part where you collect the data points of the curve into `t`, you're right, he addendum works regardless!

Comment: @spietro  As I understand it, you wish a generalization of my first solution for curves with turning points, like `x = y^2`,  One approach would be to compute `y[x]` as shown until the slope of the curve, determined numerically, first becomes large compared to '1`, then switch to computing `x[y]`.  If the slope of `x[y'] later becomes large, switch back again.  Note also that my original solution uses linear interpolation to provide an initial guess for the next point on the curve.  Higher order interpolation, say quadratic, may work better in some instances.

Comment: @spietro  All that said, the approach in the addendum is simpler and generally more reliable.  It may, however, be necessary to adjust `MaxRecursion` modestly for best results.  (Incidentally, the approach in my last comment requires that the curve being computed be continuously differentiable to at least the order of interpolation used to guess new points.)

Comment: @bbgodfrey Ohh, maybe I misunderstood.  I had thought the addendum was merely for plotting.  But I guess you meant `Union[%[[1, 1]]]` could actually be used to extract the points making up the curve?  If that works for curves with turning points that would be fantastic.  I'll try that first, thank you!

Comment: @spietro  Yes, that is exactly what I meant. Note, however, that the points are not necessarily in the order you may want, so some sorting may be necessary.  However, there is more information buried inside the `ContourPlot` (or, more precisely, inside the `GraphicsComplex` that is inside the `ContourPlot`) that makes that sorting fairly rapid.

Comment: @spietro  You also may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6806034/4339041) of use.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks, but it appears your method works perfectly for me.  I simply needed to use this (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65246/exclude-data-from-a-list) to delete those transient data points outside the main curve.  I really appreciate your help here!  Numerics is not my strong suit, and I'd been hopelessly stuck on this for quite a while.