# Interactive eraser for a ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, gui-construction

I recently had my interest peaked by the excellent thread "[Exclude data from a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65246/exclude-data-from-a-list)."  In particular, the second answer which constructs an interactive eraser which allows one to delete data points in a `ListPlot`.  For example,

```
data = Table[{RandomReal[{-10, 10}], RandomReal[{-10, 10}]}, {i, 1, 300}];
DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}, r = 3}, 
   Column[{Slider[Dynamic[r], {0.1, 5}], 
   Button["Delete", 
     data = Select[data, EuclideanDistance[#, pt] > r &]], 
   LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
     Dynamic[
       ListPlot[data, 
         Frame -> True, 
         Axes -> False, 
         AspectRatio -> 1, 
         Epilog -> Circle[pt, r],
         ImageSize -> 300]],
      Appearance -> None]}]]
```

My question is, can one do something like this with `ContourPlot`?  My idea was to make a contour plot, and then use `Union` to extract the data points, and plot them with `ListPlot` to apply the eraser:

```
F[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2 - 4;

AB = Union[ContourPlot[{F[x, y] == 0}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}][[1, 1]]];
DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}, r = 3}, 
  Column[
    {Slider[Dynamic[r], {0.1, 5}], 
     Button["Delete", AB = Select[AB, EuclideanDistance[#, pt] > r &]], 
     LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
       Dynamic[ListPlot[AB, 
         Frame -> True, 
         Axes -> False, 
         AspectRatio -> 1, 
         Epilog -> Circle[pt, r], 
         ImageSize -> 300]], 
       Appearance -> None]}]]
```

The problem with this attempt is that there's many gaps in the `ListPlot`.  So does anyone know how to improve my awful method?  Or perhaps is there another way to erase certain data points from a `ContourPlot`?  If it helps, I don't care about collecting the resulting data points at all; this is purely about plotting a result.

Comment: If `F` is really the input then taking about erasing points doesn't make sense so much. `ContourPlot[{F[x, y] == 0}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y}, EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, {2, 0}] > 1]]` is something to start with, you can also take a look at `ImplicitRegion`, `RegionDifference` and friends.

Comment: @Kuba Why exactly doesn't it make much sense?  Maybe I should have said I was hoping to erase certain points in the zero set I told ContourPlot to plot.

Comment: Because `F[x, y] == 0` represents an infinite set of points and using `Select` approach with sample point representation you will lose precission quite quickly, as you noticed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe an implementation using `ListCurvePathPlot` will work for you. With your example contour function it works well. It might not work so well for less well-behaved contours.

```
F[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2 - 4
contour = 
  Union[ContourPlot[{F[x, y] == 0}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}][[1, 1]]];

DynamicModule[{pts = contour, eraser = {0, 0}, eraserR = .2},
 Column[
   {Row[
      {Style["eraser radius ", "SR"], 
       Slider[Dynamic[eraserR], {.05, 1., .05}], " ",
       Dynamic[eraserR]}], 
    Button["Delete", 
      pts = Select[pts, EuclideanDistance[#, eraser] > eraserR &]],
    LocatorPane[Dynamic[eraser],
      Dynamic[ListCurvePathPlot[pts,
        Frame -> True,
        Axes -> False,
        PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}},
        PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05],
        Epilog -> Circle[eraser, eraserR],
        ImageSize -> 350]],
      Appearance -> None]}]]
```

Here is how it looks at start-up.

[image: initial]

And this is how it looks after some deletions.

[image: modified]