# Interactively extracting arbitrary portion of elements from a 2D list

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics

I have a 2D list which can be plotted as follows:

Image 1

[image]

Based on the plotted image, I would like to select some of the shapes on the image and extract the data for further analysis, for example,

Image 2:

[image]

Is there any interactive tool or function in Mathematica which can serve the purpose?

A sample data can be downloaded here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aY5Iq1eqhRuzJ2sQ7dtPZ3b5KONwhm58/view?usp=sharing

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to filter original data based on that selection or to crop an image to that selection. Since images are usually rectangular, what do you expect to extract based on a round selection?

Comment: this may be useful: [howto- GetCoordinatesForPointsInAPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/GetCoordinatesForPointsInAPlot.html)

Comment: I prefer to filter original data based on the selection.  I want to make a statistical analysis of the selected region.  About the round selection, the data near the edge doesn't matter a lot and nearest neighbor search (or other approximation) would be good enough.  Thanks.

Comment: somewhat related: [Exclude data from a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/65255/125)

Comment: If you click the image (within Mathematica), a toolbar will appear below. You can select a part of the image and create the corresponding mask using the "mask tool".

Comment: I am guessing the pictures are obtained from input matrix using `MatrixPlot`. By "image" and "data" in  _"select some of the shapes on the image and extract the data "_  do you mean `MatrixPlot[matrix]` and the part of `matrix` corresponding to the marked shape or  `Image[MatrixPlot[matrix]]`  and  `ImageData` for the selected part of `Image[MatrixPlot[matrix]]`?

Comment: No, I do not want to extract the selected image.  I want to extract the data over the selected region.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any interactive tool or function in Mathematica which can serve the purpose?

If you click the image (within Mathematica), a toolbar will appear below. You can select a part of the image and create the corresponding mask using the "mask tool".

[image]