# How to add Polygons (using existing Lines and Points) to MeshRegion?

Tags: computational-geometry, regions, mesh

I have a MeshRegion `N` with Points and Lines, but without Polygons. That means that `MeshCells[N, 2]` returns `{}`. My mesh looks like this:

[image: my mesh]

How can I add Polygons, made of closed set of Lines, to my MeshRegion `N`? I need it to calculate area of each domain in my mesh.

Comment: I'm assuming you want to find the white-space polygon regions in the above (not ALL possible polygons?)

Comment: It's advisable not to use capital `N` as a variable name, as it's the name of the built-in function `N`.

Comment: @Taiki, I'm sorry. It should be script capital N.

Comment: @PeterRoberge, yes. Only white-space ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may work though I'm not sure why. I made it up through trial and error, aiding by [#18514](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18514/finding-face-vertices-from-the-face-adjacency-graph). You'll need `nextCandidate` and `FindFace` from there.

First of all since you haven't provide some example data, let me generate some wireframe:

```
mesh = MeshRegion[
  MeshCoordinates[#],
  MeshCells[#, 1]
]& @ VoronoiMesh[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 2}]]
```

[image: Wireframe]

Then,

```
graph1 = Graph[
  MeshCoordinates[mesh],
  MeshCells[mesh, 1] /. Line[{start_, end_}] -> {start, end},
  VertexCoordinates -> MeshCoordinates[mesh],
  GraphLayout -> "PlanarEmbedding"
];
graph2 = Graph[
  MeshCells[mesh, 1] /. Line[{start_, end_}] -> start <-> end
];
adj = AdjacencyMatrix[graph2];
graph3 = AdjacencyGraph[adj, GraphLayout -> "PlanarEmbedding"];
faces = FindFace[graph3];
meshpolygons = MeshRegion[
  VertexList[graph1][[VertexList[graph2]]],
  Polygon /@ Most[SortBy[faces, Length]]
]
```

[image: Filled wireframe]

Then you can obtain the area of each polygon as follows:

```
Area /@ (MeshCells[meshpolygons, 2] /. x_Integer :> MeshCoordinates[meshpolygons][[x]])
```

Let's see if the method works for your specific wireframe.

Some explanation:

- Basically your problem is about detecting smallest polygons from connected lines. This requires some clever algorithm. Thankfully we have [#18514](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18514/finding-face-vertices-from-the-face-adjacency-graph). We can turn our wireframe into a graph and use the method there.
- `graph1` is the straightforward conversion. It doesn't have any crossings, but for some reason it doesn't work with `FindFace`. (I haven't taken time to study it.) Possibly the function requires its argument's structure to be of certain canonical form, so I convert `graph1` to an adjacency matrix first and then obtain `graph3`.
- `graph1` contains the actual positions of the vertices, so we need `VertexList[graph1]` in `meshpolygons`, but the **ordering** of the vertices used in `faces` is from `graph2`, hence `VertexList[graph1][[VertexList[graph2]]]`.
- `faces` also includes the largest, encompassing polygon. I assume that it has the most vertices and remove it with `Most` after sorting the list of faces by the number of their vertices.

Comment: Works nice! Thank you very much!