# Getting the area of the gaps in this image of a spider web?

Tags: image-processing, image

I'm trying to find a way to calculate the area of the gaps in a sample of spider web in a ring. The web strands are very thin and difficult to segment, since there appear to be breaks in the line where the strand is very faint. The best attempt so far has been TopHat Transform. I've tried using ImageLines to approximate the strands, but there are still breaks. Using MorphologicalGraph gets me to a similar place. So my question is twofold. What method would work to identify the lines, and how can I calculate the areas of the gaps in the webs?

[image: web sample]
Note: I am a beginner to the Wolfram Language, and may be missing some basic knowledge on how to do this. I've added a sample image to this post, for reference.

```
lines = ImageLines[Blur[TopHatTransform[web, 5]], Method -> {"Segmented" -> True}];

HighlightImage[web5, lines]

MorphologicalGraph[Binarize[Blur[TopHatTransform[web, 5]], 0.05]]
```

[image: image lines results]

[image: morphological binaries results]

Comment: Perhaps first binarize the image, then use `Dilation` to repair the lines, then invert the image and use `MorphologicalComponents` to get the areas of the regions. Optionally, `Thinning` could be applied after `Dilation`. I'm not at a computer with Mathematica at the moment so I can't try this out.

Comment: This might be a good starting point: ``DeleteSmallComponents[LocalAdaptiveBinarize[img, 20], 2000]``

Comment: And also, can you please clarify what exactly is a _gap_ in a spider web? Do you just want to get the areas of all the polygons?

Comment: Yes, I just want to get the areas of the polygons

Comment: How representative of your images is the example?  Are they all circles with a few well-spaced threads?  Do they all have the same scale?  Is the thickness (I presume a diameter but I don't know much about spiders or webs) a constant or would you want to measure that from the image?

Comment: This is a representative sample, only the pattern of polygons vary. Everything else is at the same scale and light conditions. I'm just interested in the spaces and not the diameter of the thread. [This post] (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/255164/color-regions-defined-by-many-lines) is something similar to what I'm after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is based on the initial solution by @dinesh (OP) and suggestions (very much on point) from @C. E. and @Domen.

The short version.
Input: OP's provided image.

Output:

[image: Web skeleton overlay + circular boundary (contraction explained below).]

Before explaining, I would like to note the main issues:

- The uppermost and the lowermost web thread vertices are slightly
  distorted
- Some of the field of view is lost
- The two above issues mean that there are possible non-negligible (up to the OP) errors in the web gap areas
- Based on only one image it is hard to say how robust/automatable this is

Might be able to fix these in the future, unless someone else beats me to it. For now, here is how the solution works.

It seemed from the OP's attempt that the object in the smaller gap might be a problem, so it should be removed. First one needs a mask:

```
inpaintMask = Dilation[#, DiskMatrix@3] &@Closing[#, DiskMatrix@5] &@(
  DeleteSmallComponents[#, 15] &@Binarize@# -
   ColorNegate@FillingTransform@Binarize@ColorNegate@#
  ) &@webInput;

ImageAdd[
 webInput,
 ColorReplace[#, White -> Yellow] &@EdgeDetect@inpaintMask
 ]
```

where `webInput` is the OP's image; `DeleteSmallComponents[#, 15] &@Binarize@#` detects the artefact and `-ColorNegate@FillingTransform@Binarize@ColorNegate@#` excludes the segments at the circular field of view boundary.

Dilation "bloats" the mask to better remove the artefact with inpainting:

```
webClean = Inpaint[
  webInput, inpaintMask,
  Method -> {"TextureSynthesis", "MaxSamples" -> 500, "NeighborCount" -> 50}
  ]
```

[image: Artefact removed]

which thankfully correctly fills in the upper web thread, but alas deforms the lower thread.

Now use the OP's initial solution:

```
webTopHat = ImageAdjust@TopHatTransform[#, 2] &@webClean
```

which by the way can be visualized more clearly with `2*webTopHat`. Now the threads with breaks in them can be repaired and binarized. Taking the suggestion of @C. E. but replacing dilation with Gaussian filtering before binarizing as suggested by @Domen

```
webBinarized = LocalAdaptiveBinarize[#, 15] &@
    ImageAdjust@GaussianFilter[#, 2] &@webTopHat
```

one has this:

[image: Binarization estimate]

where one has two problems: the artefacts in the web gaps and at the circular boundary. Note that applying this step without top-hat transforming the input produces coarser artefacts which are a lot harder (may not be possible in other OP's images) to get rid of. Also, the artefact that was removed previously interferes with binarization rather badly and corrupts the smaller web gap.

To remove the interior/boundary artefacts, one first needs a mask of the circular field of view. Not knowing if the other OP's images contain any boundary artefacts, the circular mask is found as follows:

```
circleMaskEstimate = 
 ImagePad[#, -10, Black] &@FillingTransform@Closing[#, 3] &@
    ImagePad[#, 10, Black] &@ColorNegate@Binarize@webClean


circleMaskEstimateContracted = 
 ImagePad[#, -10, Black] &@Erosion[#, DiskMatrix@6] &@
    ImagePad[#, 10, Black] &@circleMaskEstimate
```

where `ImagePad` (removed after operations) prevents boundary artefacts and the contracted mask `circleMaskEstimateContracted` will be used a bit later on. As a safeguard from boundary artefacts in the source images, this estimate is refined by fitting a circle:

```
    whitePixels = 
      PixelValuePositions[EdgeDetect@circleMaskEstimateContracted, 1];
    
    fitError = 
      Total[Map[Function[whitePixel, (Norm[{cx, cy} - whitePixel] - r)^2],
         whitePixels]];
    
    optimalCircle = FindMinimum[fitError, {cx, cy, r}];
    
    Image[#, ImageSize -> Medium] &@Show[
      HighlightImage[
       webClean,
       Style[Image[EdgeDetect@circleMaskEstimateContracted], Yellow]
       ],
      Graphics[
       {Red, Dashed, Circle[{cx, cy}, r] /. optimalCircle[[2]]}
       ]
      ]

imageMask = Rasterize[#, RasterSize -> ImageDimensions@webInput] &@
  Binarize@FillingTransform@HighlightImage[
     ImageAdjust@Binarize[#, 1] &@webInput,
     
     Graphics[
      {White, Thin, Circle[{cx, cy}, r] /. optimalCircle[[2]]}
      ]
     ]
```

to make sure the mask is actually circular.

Now the artefacts can be removed as follows:

```
webSkeleton = Thinning@ImageMultiply[#, imageMask] &@webBinarized

webSkeletonClean = DeleteSmallComponents[#, 500] &@
    Pruning[#, 15] &@webSkeleton

webSkeletonCorrected = 
 Pruning[#, 10] &@Thinning@Binarize@GaussianFilter[#, 5] &@
  webSkeletonClean
```

where `webSkeleton` crops the segment with the contracted circular mask and then performs thinning; `webSkeletonClean` performs pruning, *then* size thresholding (easier to clean artefacts this way, since they are finer); `webSkeletonCorrected` removes any remaining "parasitic" branches and loops.

[image: Preliminary skeleton]

From here the strategy is this:

- Use the branch points of the web skeleton and its intersection points with the circular boundary to reconstruct corrupted/incomplete web gaps (like the smaller one in this case)
- Invert the reconstructed skeleton + the circular boundary (with some modifications)
- Get the web gap segments and measure their areas

Start by joining (as non-destructively as I could manage) the clean web skeleton with the circular boundary

```
webSkeletonPlusCirclePadded = ImagePad[#, 25, Black] & /@ {
    EdgeDetect@imageMask,
    webSkeletonCorrected
    } // ImageAdd


webPlusCircleSkeleton = 
 Binarize[#, 10^-6] &@Thinning@ImageMultiply[#, imageMask] &@
      ImagePad[#, -25, Black] &@
    Binarize@GaussianFilter[#, 4] &@webSkeletonPlusCirclePadded
```

where `webSkeletonPlusCirclePadded` adds the circle and the web skeleton, and prepares some safe space for operations with `ImagePad`; a merged skeleton is then produced with `webPlusCircleSkeleton` by bridging the gaps using Gaussian filtering and binarization followed by thinning.

Then the branch points are found for the resulting skeleton:

```
allBranchPoints = MorphologicalBranchPoints@webPlusCircleSkeleton;

HighlightImage[
 webPlusCircleSkeleton,
 Style[#, Red] &@allBranchPoints
 ]
```

[image: Joined skeleton + highlighted branchpoints]

The fragments of incomplete edges are detected with

```
incompleteEdges = 
 ImageDifference @@ {#, Pruning@#} &@webPlusCircleSkeleton
```

and the vertices that must be joined to reconstruct the missing edges are found via

```
verticesToJoin = ImageSubtract[#, incompleteEdges] &@
    DeleteSmallComponents[#, 1] &@ImageAdd[
   incompleteEdges,
   allBranchPoints
   ]
```

where `ImageDifference @@ {#, Pruning@#}` prunes the branches of incomplete edges to then find them as a difference from the unpruned image. `verticesToJoin` identifies branch points to be connected as those that are adjacent to the the branches of incomplete edges (`DeleteSmallComponents[#, 1]` removes all other points).

Here only one pair of vertices must be joined, but in general one would need to first identify pairs. Here the OP's idea with `ImageLines` could be useful, since the point pairs to be joined belong to branches of incomplete edges - their line orientations can be found (e.g. using RANSAC as a `Method`, since they may be rather jagged) and then pairs can be identified based on combined angle/Euclidean distances between their respective lines (i.e. using `CosineDistance` as a `DistanceFunction`).

Once that is done, the corrupted edges are recovered using the Bresenham's line algorithm (credit to @halirutan, [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45753/bresenhams-line-algorithm)):

```
bresenhamLine[p0_, p1_] := 
 Module[{dx, dy, sx, sy, err, newp}, {dx, dy} = Abs[p1 - p0];
  {sx, sy} = Sign[p1 - p0];
  err = dx - dy;
  newp[{x_, y_}] := 
   With[{e2 = 2 err}, {If[e2 > -dy, err -= dy; x + sx, x], 
     If[e2 < dx, err += dx; y + sy, y]}];
  NestWhileList[newp, p0, # =!= p1 &, 1]]

recoveredEdgePixelCoordinates = 
  bresenhamLine @@ PixelValuePositions[#, 1] &@verticesToJoin;

recoveredEdges = ReplacePixelValue[
  verticesToJoin,
  # -> 1 & /@ recoveredEdgePixelCoordinates
  ]
```

allowing to finally get the solution skeleton:

```
webPlusCircleSkeletonFixed = ImageAdd[
  webPlusCircleSkeleton,
  -incompleteEdges,
  recoveredEdges
  ]
```

Perhaps there is a better way of doing this, but the web gaps can now be resolved as follows:

```
resolvedSegments = 
  ColorNegate@Dilation[#, DiskMatrix@0.5] &@webPlusCircleSkeletonFixed;
```

and visualized like this:

```
resolvedSegmentsColorized = 
 Colorize@MorphologicalComponents@resolvedSegments
```

[image: Web gaps resolved]

Alternatively, the very first image in this answer was generated with

```
finalSkeletonOverlay = ImageAdd[
  webInput,
  webPlusCircleSkeletonFixed
  ]
```

At last, the segment areas can be determined:

```
segmentStats = ComponentMeasurements[
     #, {"MaskedImage", "Area"}
     ] &@resolvedSegments;

Last /@ segmentStats[[2 ;; All]] // TableForm
```

[image]

But whether the quality is acceptable is, of course, for the OP to decide. This should be rather robust, but also has a few minor issues that are best answered in comments, should they become critical. Also, I would like to thank the OP for an interesting problem! Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much for all the effort you put into this. I deeply appreciate it. You have introduced me to several concepts and it will take some time for me to assimilate this. I will update here when I try it on other images.

Comment: Glad to hear this is of use! If some of the steps are unclear, please let me know. I can add more images now, if need be. If you run into problems with your other images and are willing to send a few more examples, I could have another look. Also, depending on your hardware and the number of images, optimization/parallelization could be worth it. Haven't tried putting things together in one `Module` and running on multiple (duplicate) images.

Comment: looks like you were right about other images, I'm having trouble reproducing the output if there are differences in the images

Comment: What exactly are the differences? Your OP mentions that illumination and scales should be the same. Could you show a few more representative examples?

Comment: I have a folder here of the ring images. Note that in these, the rings are not circularly cropped as in the example above https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dbd1c674k6oh87i/AABqA93LcnCdXSspQnYnTCq4a?dl=0

Comment: Got the files, thank you! I can take care of the cropping, no problem. No idea how fast I can get to this, but I will try to get back to you sometime during February.