# How to create a planar graph from a set of random points

Tags: graphs-and-networks, computational-geometry

**Question**

Given a set of points in the plane, how can you create a planar graph in the standard graph representation of *Mathematica* (version 9 or higher), from these points?

**Background**

A planar graph is a graph embedded in the plane in such a way that the edges intersect at vertices only. This is an example of a planar graph:

```
g = GridGraph[{3, 3}]
```

[image: GridGraph]

It is stored in the standard *Mathematica* representation for graphs.

You can also draw a planar graph from a set of points in the plane with `` ComputationalGeometry`PlanarGraphPlot ``:

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"]    
pts = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {10, 2}]
PlanarGraphPlot[pts]
```

[image: Delaunay triangulation of points]

However, the output is **not** in the standard representation for graphs.

Comment: Hi sjdh - now that I re-read your question, I think I misunderstood what you are looking for. Can you clarify, perhaps a small example of what the input/output should be?

Comment: @sjdh You basically want to be able to draw a planar graph with the new Graph objects instead of the old graph methods used in Mathematica 7?

Comment: I've edited your question, please check if I got your intention correctly. Feel free to roll back if not.

Comment: @IstvánZachar You've got my intention. Thank you for your edit.

Comment: @bills Using the words of IstvánZachar, I like to "build a graph by collecting all the edges of a Delaunay triangulation"

Comment: Related: [How to plot planar graphs as such?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1781/how-to-plot-planar-graphs-as-such).

Comment: I have an implementation of this here (in the question itself): http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1781/12

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In **Version 10**, we can do this nicely even for 3D point sets:

```
pointsToGraph[pts_, graph : (Graph | Graph3D)] := 
 Module[{del = DelaunayMesh[pts], edges},
  edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ MeshCells[del, 1][[All, 1]];
  graph[Range@Length@pts, edges, VertexLabels -> "Name", VertexCoordinates -> pts]
  ]

SeedRandom[2];
pts2d = RandomReal[10, {10, 2}];
pointsToGraph[pts2d, Graph]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
SeedRandom[2];
pts3d = RandomReal[10, {30, 3}];
pointsToGraph[pts3d, Graph3D]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 8):

Using [Mark McClure's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22220/89), one can easily build a graph by collecting all the edges of a Delaunay triangulation and then removing duplicates. For non-crossing layout, use `GraphLayout -> "PlanarEmbedding"` (since v9) and add the original points as vertex coordinates.

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"];
pts = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {10, 2}];
dt = DelaunayTriangulation[pts];
toPairs[{m_, ns_List}] := Map[{m, #} &, ns];
edges = Union[Sort /@ Flatten[toPairs /@ dt, 1]];
Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 20,
    GraphLayout -> "PlanarEmbedding", VertexCoordinates -> pts]
```

[image]

Comment: In your example, some edges cross each other. I would like a result in which non of the edges cross. I'll add this to my question.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one possibility, using an undocumented function for the Delaunay triangulation:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[131, Method -> "MKL"]; (* for reproducibility *)
            pts = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {10, 2}]];

Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];
dt = Delaunay[pts];

Graph[Range[Length[pts]], UndirectedEdge @@@ dt["Edges"], VertexCoordinates -> pts]
```

[image: Delaunay graph from randomly chosen points]

Compare:

```
GraphicsComplex[dt["Coordinates"],
                {FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Black], Polygon[dt["Faces"]]}] // Graphics
```

[image: Delaunay triangles]

Answer (score 2):

With [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM),

```
pts = RandomPoint[Disk[], 10];

IGMeshGraph@DelaunayMesh[pts]
```

[image]